# Go Struct JSON array of arrays

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I´m having problems trying to mapping some data from specific Request Response because inside *seriesLabels*: there are data without property names (int,string) so I'm confused how to map that data:

This is the service response:

```
{
"data": {
    "seriesLabels": [
        [
            0,
            "(none)"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Cerveza"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Cigarros"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Tecate"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Cafe"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Amstel"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Leche"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Ultra"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Coca cola"
        ],
        [
            0,
            "Agua"
        ]
    ]
}
}
```

My go struct to map that info is:

```
type PopularWord struct {
    Data *Data `json:"data"`
}

type Data struct {
    SeriesLabels []*SeriesLabels `json:"seriesLabels"`
}

type SeriesLabels struct {
    value int32  `json:""`
    name  string `json:""`
}
```

What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to declare the structs?

Comment: You could take a look at this (very) useful site https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seriesLabels` is a JSON array, and its elements are also JSON arrays.

To parse a JSON array of arrays, you may use a slice of slices in Go:

```
type Data struct {
    SeriesLabels [][]interface{}
}
```

Testing it:

```
var pw *PopularWord
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &pw); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(pw)
for _, sl := range pw.Data.SeriesLabels {
    fmt.Println(sl)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4slLP6So4Jv)):

```
&{0xc000120108}
[0 (none)]
[0 Cerveza]
[0 Cigarros]
[0 Tecate]
[0 Cafe]
[0 Amstel]
[0 Leche]
[0 Ultra]
[0 Coca cola]
[0 Agua]
```

To get the inner arrays as struct values, you may implement custom unmarshaling:

```
type Data struct {
    SeriesLabels []*SeriesLabels `json:"seriesLabels"`
}

type SeriesLabels struct {
    value int32 
    name  string
}

func (sl *SeriesLabels) UnmarshalJSON(p []byte) error {
    var s []interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(p, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if len(s) > 0 {
        if f, ok := s[0].(float64); ok {
            sl.value = int32(f)
        }
    }

    if len(s) > 1 {
        if s, ok := s[1].(string); ok {
            sl.name = s
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Testing code is the same, output (try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iVL-lH46Mer)):

```
&{0xc0000aa0f0}
&{0 (none)}
&{0 Cerveza}
&{0 Cigarros}
&{0 Tecate}
&{0 Cafe}
&{0 Amstel}
&{0 Leche}
&{0 Ultra}
&{0 Coca cola}
&{0 Agua}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `SeriesLabels` is represented in JSON as an array. If you want to use `encoding/json`, you have to implement the [Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface to decode it (otherwise it will only accept JSON objects).

Fortunately, the code is simple:

```golang
func (s *SeriesLabels) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    arr := []interface{}{&s.value, &s.name}
    return json.Unmarshal(d, &arr)
}
```

Note that this code ignores invalid input (array too long, or incorrect type). Depending on your needs, you may wish to add checks after the call to `json.Unmarshal` that the array length and contents (pointers) have not changed.

There are other JSON parsing libraries for Go that make this a bit less cumbersome, like [gojay](https://github.com/francoispqt/gojay).